# Publishing my asp.net mvc application via script and not Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, msbuild

I dont really know much about this to be honest with you...

I have managed to download mscommunity build and I have managed to use the script below to successfully compile and build my application, however I want to get my asp.net mvc application "published" so I want the same files that you when clicking "publish" inside visual studio. My current build file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <!-- Import the MSBuild Tasks -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <ClassLibraryOutputDirectory>c:\publish\</ClassLibraryOutputDirectory>
    <ProjectDir>..\PetProject\</ProjectDir >
    <ProjectTestDir>$(ProjectDir)PetProject.WebUI\</ProjectTestDir >
    <ProjectFile>$(ProjectDir)PetProject.sln</ProjectFile >
    <TestProjectFile>$(ProjectTestDir)PetProject.WebUI.csproj</TestProjectFile >
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Build projects by calling the Project files generated by VS -->
  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(TestProjectFile)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

I call this in command line using:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5>msbuild.exe C:\Projects\PetProject\build
\PetProject.build
```

Help is greatly appreciated...

NOTE: I want to avoid CI, Nant etc. because I dont really know what they are and I ideally want to get the above working as First Base, then move onto other things like CI or whatever else, I dont want to confuse myself too much...

Answer (score 4):

This should give you the same result as publishing from within Visual Studio:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildAndPublish" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <ProjectFile>C:\PetProject\PetProject.csproj</ProjectFile >
        <OutDir>C:\PetProject\MyPublish</OutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="BuildAndPublish">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=Release;PackageLocation=$(OutDir)\MSDeploy\Package.zip;_PackageTempDir=$(OutDir)\Temp" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

for your project.

Don't forget to import `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` which contains the `Package` target (which I mixed up with `Publish` in my inital answer).

If you want to build your solution your script should look something like this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildAndPublish" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutDir>C:\PetProject\MyPublish\</OutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Solution Include="C:\PetProject\PetProject.sln">
            <Properties>
                OutDir=$(OutDir);
                Platform=Any CPU;
                Configuration=Release;
                DeployOnBuild=True;
                DeployTarget=Package;
                PackageLocation=$(OutDir)\MSDeploy\Package.zip;
                _PackageTempDir=$(OutDir)\Temp
            </Properties>
        </Solution>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="BuildAndPublish">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(Solution)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

There's [a blog post by Code Inside](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2010/11/21/howto-msdeploy-msbuild/) which describes basically the same approach but didn't work when I tried it in my environment.

Comment: How would I target the publish to output to my output directory? I could not get that bit...

Comment: Sorry that my inital answer didn't work - I mixed up `Publish` (which only works for ClickOnce deployable projects and `Package`.

Comment: Its cool... I assume this requires visual studio to be on the server? (My server does not have visual studio installed! :( )

Comment: Sorry my application is Asp.net MVC2 targeting asp.net 3.5 not 4.0

Comment: @Haroon I'll see if I can set up an example with your specs - it should be possible without VS on your build machine.